# how to invalidate parent window without sending wm_paint to child window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdk, gdi

the parent and the child window is in the same size.
and the the parent listens to the child's repainting
when child repainting, the parent repainting.
so I cannot use invalidate to clean the parent window,
cos this will send wm_paint to child window, then a endless cycle.

how can i clean up parent widnow without use invalidateRect,invalidateRgn and so on.
or, how can i invalidate parent without send wm_paint to child window?

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on your window, or try calling the [RedrawWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms913080.aspx) function specifying `RDW_NOCHILDREN` as the final parameter. This may do what you want, although it's somewhat difficult to tell.